# PHP MVC Namespacing and Aliasing

Tags: php, model-view-controller, namespaces, aliases

I'm trying to learn PHP better my working on my custom framework (learning purposes) and I was wondering how can I implement namespaces with aliases (they're new to me). My "framework" structure look like:

```
app/
    controllers/
    core/
    functions/
    languages/
    models/
    vendor/
    views/
    .htaccess
    composer.json
    composer.lock
    config.php
    database.php
    filters.php
    index.php
    init.php
    routes.php
style/
upload/
.htaccess
index.php
robots.txt
```

In app/core folder I have files:

```
App.php
Controller.php
Filter.php
Functions.php
Language.php
Route.php
index.php
```

And my init.php file looks like:

```
<?php
    require "vendor/autoload.php";
    require "database.php";
    require "core/App.php";
    require "core/Filter.php";
    require "core/Route.php";
    require "functions/Common.php";
    require "functions/Validator.php";
    require "functions/Custom.php";
    require "core/Language.php";
    require "core/Functions.php";
    require "core/Controller.php";
```

Files from controllers/ folder extend Controller.php, and core/Functions.php extends core/Custom.php which extends core/Common.php
How can I implement namespacing and alisaing so I can make my framework easier for maintaining and not needing to load every class with full namespace? Thanks in advance

**Edit**:
Ok I've created a file controller.php in app/controllers/ with this code

```
<?php
    use App\Core\Controller as BaseController;

    class Controller extends BaseController {

    }
```

And in my App.php I added the following function:

```
    private function applyAliases() {
        foreach(self::$config['aliases'] as $file => $alias) {
            class_alias($file, $alias);
        }
    }
```

So in my config.php file i added:

```
/* Aliases */
"aliases" => [
    "App\Core\Language" => "Language",
    "App\Core\Filter" => "Filter",
    "App\Core\Route" => "Route"
]
```

Also, in Functions.php when loading functions i added another class_alias:

```
public function loadFunction(string $file) {
    if(!file_exists(App::$config['paths']['functions'].$file.".php")) {
        throw new Exception("File ".App::$config['paths']['functions'].$file.".php doesn't exists");
    }

    require App::$config['paths']['functions'].$file.".php";

    class_alias("App\Functions\\".$file, $file);

    return new $file();
}
```

Would this be the proper way?

Comment: Have you read [PHP documentation on namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php)?

Comment: Are you sure that you don't want asking about autoloading first?

Comment: @JiriHrazdil Of course. I am asking this question because i have no idea how to implement aliases so that i don't have to call every class with it's namespace like `class UserController extends \App\Core\Controller`
@Federkun Autoloading is the next thing I want to improve after this

Comment: If your `UserController` class is in `\App\Controllers` namespace and you want to extend class `Controller` from `\App\Core` namespace, you must use fully qualified class name `\App\Core\Controller`. If you want to just use `class UserController extends Controller`, you'll have to put those classes in the same namespace.

Comment: Ok I now a workaround for that without moving file (create new file in controllers folder that extends App\Core\Controller) and then extend that class. But how can I call classes from let's say App\Functions with alias? Where would be the best location to write my aliases?

Comment: You don't need to move your files with namespaces (directory structure can be independent of your namespace structure). The best place to write your aliases is directly below your namespace declaration. Again, see [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) for examples.

Comment: I've updated my question with changes